# SQL query not returning results when selecting multiple "category" or "type"

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I'm trying to implement a SQL query. When selecting one category or type from the html search form it works correctly, however once I select more than one category or type, it doesn't return any results (although the database consist of those entries). Could someone please advise what would be the correct way to structure the query?

```
    public static function paginatesearch($location, $bedrooms, $bathrooms, $minamount, $maxamount, $forsale, $torent, $holidayaccommodation, $house, $apartment, $duplex, $simplex, $lodge, $campsite, $hotel, $commercial, $industrial, $land, $sortby)
    {
        $db = static::getDB();

        $sql = 'SELECT *,

        posts.id as postId,
        users.id as userId,
        posts.created_at as postCreated,
        users.created_at as userCreated
        FROM posts
        INNER JOIN users
        ON posts.user_id = users.id

        WHERE coverimage != "default.jpg"
        
        AND location = :location';
        

        if ($bedrooms != '') {
            $sql .= ' AND bedrooms = :bedrooms';
        }
        if ($bathrooms != '') {
            $sql .= ' AND bathrooms = :bathrooms';
        }
        if ($minamount != '') {
            $sql .= ' AND amount >= :minamount';
        }
        if ($maxamount != '') {
            $sql .= ' AND amount <= :maxamount';
        }

        if ($forsale != '') {
            $sql .= ' AND category = :forsale';
        }

        if ($torent != '') {
            $sql .= ' AND category = :torent';
        }

        if ($holidayaccommodation != '') {
            $sql .= ' AND category = :holidayaccommodation';
        }


        if ($house != '') {
            $sql .= ' AND type = :house';
        }

        if ($apartment != '') {
            $sql .= ' AND type = :apartment';
        }
        if ($duplex != '') {
            $sql .= ' AND type = :duplex';
        }
        if ($simplex != '') {
            $sql .= ' AND type = :simplex';
        }
        if ($lodge != '') {
            $sql .= ' AND type = :lodge';
        }
        if ($campsite != '') {
            $sql .= ' AND type = :campsite';
        }
        if ($hotel != '') {
            $sql .= ' AND type = :hotel';
        }
        if ($commercial != '') {
            $sql .= ' AND type = :commercial';
        }
        if ($industrial != '') {
            $sql .= ' AND type = :industrial';
        }
        if ($land != '') {
            $sql .= ' AND type = :land';
        }


        if ($sortby == 'newest') {
            $sql .="\nORDER BY posts.created_at DESC";
        }

        if ($sortby == 'oldest') {
            $sql .="\nORDER BY posts.created_at ASC";
        }

        if ($sortby == 'highest') {
            $sql .= "\nORDER BY posts.amount DESC";
        }

        if ($sortby == 'lowest') {
            $sql .= "\nORDER BY posts.amount ASC";
        }


        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
     
        $stmt->bindValue(':location', $location, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    
        if ($bedrooms != '') {
            $stmt->bindValue(':bedrooms', $bedrooms, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        }
        if ($bathrooms != '') {
            $stmt->bindValue(':bathrooms', $bathrooms, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        }
        if ($minamount != '') {
            $stmt->bindValue(':minamount', $minamount, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        }
        if ($maxamount != '') {
            $stmt->bindValue(':maxamount', $maxamount, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }

        if ($forsale != '') {
            $stmt->bindValue(':forsale', $forsale, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }
        if ($torent != '') {
            $stmt->bindValue(':torent', $torent, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }

        if ($holidayaccommodation != '') {
            $stmt->bindValue(':holidayaccommodation', $holidayaccommodation, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }
      
        if ($house != '') {
            $stmt->bindValue(':house', $house, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }

        if ($apartment != '') {
            $stmt->bindValue(':apartment', $apartment, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }
        if ($duplex != '') {
            $stmt->bindValue(':duplex', $duplex, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }
        if ($simplex != '') {
            $stmt->bindValue(':simplex', $simplex, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }
        if ($lodge != '') {
            $stmt->bindValue(':lodge', $lodge, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }
        if ($campsite != '') {
            $stmt->bindValue(':campsite', $campsite, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }
        if ($hotel != '') {
            $stmt->bindValue(':hotel', $hotel, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }
        if ($commercial != '') {
            $stmt->bindValue(':commercial', $commercial, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }
        if ($industrial != '') {
            $stmt->bindValue(':industrail', $industrial, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }
        if ($land != '') {
            $stmt->bindValue(':land', $land, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }

        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: `category` (or any other column for that matter) cannot have more than one value per row, so an expression like `category = 'something' AND category = 'something else'` will never evaluate to true for any row. You might want `OR` or `IN`.

Comment: You could define an array in first `if`s then bind that in the execute.. that would eliminate need for second `if`s. e.g. `if ($bedrooms != '') { $sql .= ' AND bedrooms = :bedrooms'; $params['bedroom'] = $bedrooms;` }`

Comment: @stickybit Thank you for your reply. I have implemented "OR" statements and have set the check boxes in the html form as default to checked. It is now working correctly - thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason multiple categories do not work is because you are combining them with "and", but you should be combining them with "or"


Currently you are ending up with `where type = 'simplex' AND type = 'lodge'`
You should be having `where (type = 'simplex' OR type = 'lodge')'`
"or" statements should be inclosed inside of `( )`

Another solution would be passing categories as an array and using the IN statement as such `where type in ('lodge', 'simplex')`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have implemented "OR" statements and have set the check boxes in the html form as default to checked. It is now working correctly - thank you.